# std::transform with two std::vector and one constant as arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, transform, stdvector

i want to use std::transform to do something similar to binary_op but with one additional constant, for example, to get a product of two vectors:
 x1 = (10,20,30,40,50) and x2 = (2,4,6,8,10), we can write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


double multiply(double x, double y){
    return x*y;
}

int main () {
  std::vector<int> x1;
  std::vector<int> x2;


  for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
    x1.push_back (i*10); //10,20,30,40,50

  for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
    x2.push_back (i*2);  //2,4,6,8,10



  std::transform (x1.begin(), x1.end(), x2.begin(), x1.begin(),multiply);


  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=x1.begin(); it!=x1.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  //output: 20,80,180,320,500

  return 0;
}
```

The above code will multiply x1 and x2 elementwise and return (20,80,180,320,500).

However, if i want to calculate x1 $\dot$ x2 + c, where c is a scalar constant such as 1, like the function below:

```
double multiply(double x, double y, double c){
    return x*y + c;
}
```

In this case, how can i use std::transform to apply on two vectors x1 and x2? do i have to make the scalar constant c to become a vector with the same elements like (c,c,c...c)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered `std::bind` ?

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
int c = 20;
std::transform (x1.begin(), x1.end(), x2.begin(), x1.begin(),[&c](auto i, auto j) { return  multiply(i,j) + c ; });
```

It is lambda function; i is the element from x1, j is element from x2. [&] signalizing capturing all values defined outside the lambda by reference.

Comment: @skeller Why not? The only difference between capturing all and capturing explicitly is that the latter makes it more obvious what names from the outer scope are used, which isn't really necessary for one liners.

Comment: @Cubic because its a bad practice. you capture way more than you expect, e.g. the ´this´ pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You do this by supplying a functor, i.e. a struct that has a call operator that does what you want. The old way to do this would be to do something like this:

```
struct MultWithConstantAdder {
   const double adder;
   MultWithConstantAdder(double adder): adder(adder) {}
   double operator()(double x, double y) { return add(x,y,adder); }
};
// ... rest of your code
std::transform(x1.begin(), x2.end(), x2.begin(), x1.begin(), MultWithConstantAdder(someConstantThatYouWant));
```

C++11 adds lambdas which let you do this in place without having to define a struct in some other part of the code:

```
std::transform(x1.begin(), x2.end(), x2.begin(), x1.begin(),
  [](double x, double y) { return add(x,y, someConstant); });
```

The syntax might look a bit funky if you're not used to it, but this basically does the same thing as the thing above.

The `[]` part in the lambda determines what parts of the outer scope (i.e. everything that's not in the lambda itself) should be visible. `[]` means nothing, `[=]` means everything copied by value, and `[&]` means everything visible by reference. You can also just name things directly, so for example `[someConstant, &someOtherConstant]` would capture `someConstant` by value and `someOtherConstant` by reference.

Comment: You have explained the lambda capture; but, missed to capture `someConstant` to the lambda in your second example. :)

Comment: @JeJo The examples are pseudocode, so obviously you could put a literal there too. That being said, you only need captures for local scope anyway - if `someConstant` is in the global scope, you don't need to put it in the capture list.

Comment: in this case, `someConstant` comes under local scope of lambda, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the scalar in a lambda:

```
double c = 1
std::transform (x1.begin(), x1.end(), x2.begin(), x1.begin(), [c]
    (double x, double y){
       return x*y + c;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `multiply(double x, double y)` function. Using a simple lambda, you can do all the multiplication and addition you want to do.

```
int c = 2;
std::transform (x1.begin(), x1.end(), x2.begin(), x1.begin(),
[&c](const auto& x1_ele, const auto& x2_ele){ return (x1_ele*x2_ele) + c;  });
```

---

I am not sure, is this a perfect case to deal with `std::transform`, since you can achieve the same using much simpler `std::for_each` like follows. An extra varible (`index`) is necessary though.

```
int index = 0;
int c = 2;
std::for_each(x1.begin(), x1.end(), [&](auto& x1_ele){ x1_ele = (x1_ele*x2[index]) + c; ++index; });
```

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

> `std::transform` does not guarantee in-order application of unary_op
>   or binary_op. To apply a function to a sequence in-order or to apply a
>   function that modifies the elements of a sequence, use `std::for_each`

Comment: Your `for_each` example is more, not _less_ complicated than the transform (requires keeping track of a separate index and uses two different ways to try to access things at the same location).

Also, all instances of `for_each` can be replaced by a for-each loop, which has somewhat easier to understand syntax.

Comment: @Cubic I have already mentioned about extra variable `index`, in my answer. That was however, one suggestion to the OPs problem, even he didn't ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `std::bind` ?

For example:

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

double multiply(double x, double y, double c){
    return x*y + c;
}

//in main()
  //scallar is 10.0 in this case --> last parameter.
  auto multiplyScalar = bind(&multiply, _1, _2, 10.0);

  transform(x1.begin(), x1.end(), x2.begin(), x1.begin(), multiplyScalar);
```